# Arduino Nano and analog joystick

Tags: arduino

I have a game that consist of 4 direction of movement (up down left and right) 
using Arduino Nano and analog joystick, seems like code is right as check before other posts.

This is the Arduino code:

```cpp
byte x_axis = A3;
byte y_axis = A1;
byte btn1 = 8;
byte btn2 = 9;
byte btn3 = 10;
byte btn4 = 11;
byte btn5 = 12;
byte led = 13;

void setup(){
  pinMode(x_axis, INPUT);
  pinMode(y_axis, INPUT);

  pinMode(btn1, INPUT);
  pinMode(btn2, INPUT);
  pinMode(btn3, INPUT);
   pinMode(btn4, INPUT);
   pinMode(btn5, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(btn1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(btn2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(btn3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(btn4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(btn5, HIGH);

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){

  Int read_x = analogRead(x_axis);
  int read_y = analogRead(y_axis);

  if(read_x > 600){
    Serial.println("R");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  if(read_x < 400){
    Serial.println("L");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  if(read_y > 600){
    Serial.println("D");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  if(read_y < 400){
    Serial.println("U");
   digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }

  if(digitalRead(btn1) == LOW){
    Serial.println("1");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  if(digitalRead(btn2) == LOW){
    Serial.println("2");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
   }
  if(digitalRead(btn3) == LOW){
    Serial.println("3");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
   }
  if(digitalRead(btn4) == LOW){
    Serial.println("4");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
   if(digitalRead(btn5) == LOW){
    Serial.println("5");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
   }

   delay(10);
   digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
}
```

But when I use serial monitor to check it, it non stop show me `U` and `L` even without touching the joystick.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Fix your circuit.

Comment: To fix your circuit, it will help to directly print out the values read on the two axes. From there, you'll be able to tell if your circuit is wrong, or if your chosen values are off.

Comment: i tried just Arduino without any circuit but still it shows random values

Comment: @Emadmohseny That's to be expected. If you don't have anything connected the values at the analog input will be due to whatever noise and random fluctuations are present. You will not get anything meaningful without connecting an input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling generous, so you have some jitter issues in the code and you really could use some cleanup. This code compiles. Ok now when a joystick is 0,0 in x/y physically it jitters in code. One thing you could do is remap out the jitter to give a wider center. print the raw analog values to the serial monitor and then map them out to your 0 point with a little padding. reference:  https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/

```
byte x_axis = A3;
byte y_axis = A1;
byte btn[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}; // 2,3,4,5,6
byte stat[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
byte led = 13;
int dval = 50;

void setup() {
  pinMode(x_axis, INPUT);
  pinMode(y_axis, INPUT);

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pinMode(btn[i], INPUT);
    digitalWrite(btn[i], HIGH);
  }
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  int read_x = analogRead(x_axis);
  delay(dval);
  int read_y = analogRead(y_axis);
  delay(dval);

  if (read_x > 600) {
    Serial.println("R");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  if (read_x < 400) {
    Serial.println("L");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  if (read_y > 600) {
    Serial.println("D");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  if (read_y < 400) {
    Serial.println("U");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (digitalRead(btn[i]) == LOW) {
      Serial.println(stat[i]);
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    }
  }
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Emad joon:
1- Check that the ground of your joy stick and the Vdd is connected to your arduino.

2- connect the x and y of the joy stick to the arduino analog inputs.

use this code as starter:

```
#define X_AXIS A1
#define Y_AXIS A3


void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("X = ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(X_AXIS);
  Serial.print("Y = ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(Y_AXIS);
  delay(150);

}
```

See what values you get when your Joy Stick is at initial position. You can build up on this code for buttons.
Also, do not forget to use debouncing for your button readings:

```
if(digitalRead(Button1)==0){
  delay(40);
  if(digitalRead(Button1==0){
    buttonPressed=true;
  }
}
```